# Kotlin scope functions with vs extension run

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension, extension-function

From what I've learned, it seems like extension function `T.run` and `with` have kind of the same purpose of creating the possibility to group multiple calls on the same object, returning lambda's last object as its result.

`T.run()` has the advantage of applying check for nullability before using it. (as this [article](https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84) points it out)

What are the advantages of using `with`? or better said: What stops me from always using `T.run()` instead? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case for many scope functions, you can't always tell which one is "correct" to be used, it's often the developer's choice actually. As for `with` and `run`, the only difference is how the receiver of the scope function comes into play:

On the one hand, the receiver is passed as an argument to `with`:

```
val s: String = with(StringBuilder("init")) {
    append("some").append("thing")
    println("current value: $this")
    toString()
}
```

On the other hand, `run` directly gets called on the receiver (extension function):

```
val s: String = StringBuilder("init").run {
    append("some").append("thing")
    println("current value: $this")
    toString()
}
```

`run` has the advantage of nullability-handling since the safe operator can be applied:

```
val s: String = nullableSB?.run {
   //...
} ?: "handle null case"
```

I haven’t seen many usages of `run` whereas `with` is more commonly used I think.

Answer (score 1):

As you've said, they function identically, other than the ability of using `run` with a safe call, and using it in chained expressions, for example:

```
foo.bar().run { qwert() }
```

The real difference is in the syntax - use whichever provides better readability in your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `with` onto next line, which can be more readable if you have long initializer:

```
val obj = VeryLongInitializer().DoSomething().AnotherThing()
with (obj) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

vs

```
val obj = VeryLongInitializer().DoSomething().AnotherThing().run {
    // Do stuff
}
```